# Haskell newtype that reverses or flips order

Tags: haskell, newtype

There's probably already a `newtype` that flips the sense of Ord, Bounded, etc. Something along the lines of

```
newtype FlipOrd a = FlipOrd {unFlip :: a} deriving (Eq)

instance (Ord a) => Ord (FlipOrd a) where
    compare = flip compare

instance (Bounded a) => Bounded (FlipOrd a) where
    minBound = FlipOrd maxBound
    maxBound = FlipOrd minBound
```

Where does this live in the existing Haskell packages?

Note: There's an existing `Reverse` `Functor`, which does something very different, and fortunately has a completely incompatible kind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's simply in `Data.Ord`: [`Down`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Ord.html#Down). (This doesn't have a `Bounded` instance, though.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't object to duplicating instances like I do types; if it gets added in some other code the compiler will tell me about it and it's easy to fix (simply remove one instance).